# Conditional Probability clarification

Tags: probability

Here's a sample problem:

Before each workout, I either drink a cup of coffee, a gatorade, or a cup of water.

The probability of coffee is P(C) = 0.6,

the probability of gator is P(G) = 0.3,

the probability of water is P(W) = 0.1.

If I drink coffee, the probability that the my workout ends early is 0.2.

If I drink gatorade, the probability that the workout
ends early is 0.1.

If I drink water, the workout never ends early.

**Conditioned on the event that I don’t drink water, what’s the probability that I finish the workout early?**

Let $W_c$ be the event in which I dont drink water. I worked out a tree in which $$P(Event) = 0.73$$

I know I am looking for P(Event|$W_c$). I also know that
$$W_c = 0.9$$ So is  P(Event|$W_c$) just P(Event)?

This is the formula I used to derive that.
$$P(Event \mid W_c) = \frac{P(Event \cap W_c)}{P(W_c)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $E$ be the event the workout ends early. Then 
$$\Pr(E\mid W^c)=\frac{\Pr(E\cap W^c)}{\Pr(W^c)}.$$
You have calculated $\Pr(W^c)$. We now need to find $\Pr(E\cap W^c)$.

The event $E\cap W^c$ can happen in two ways: (i) we drink coffee and the workout ends early, or (ii) we drink the commercial drink and the workout ends early.

The probability of (i) is $(0.6)(0.2)$. I am sure you can complete the calculation.

Comment: Isn't $ P(Event \cap W_c)$ = P(E)P($W_c$)?

Comment: It isn't, What you call Event and $W^c$  are not independent.

Comment: Ok. So P(E) = (0.6)(0.2)+(0.3)(0.1)+(0.9)? I guess I'm a little confused on where the $W_c$ ends up fitting on the formula

Comment: The probability of $E\cap W^c$ is $(0.6)(0.2)+(0.3)(0.1)$. For the conditional probability asked for, divide by $0.9$.